# TableView does not load realm database values

Tags: database, uitableview, swift3, realm, xmppframework

I have used **XMPPFramework**, since the user authentication and receiving only messages is done using XMPP. I am sending messages using **RestApi**. I have parsed the received xml message using **SwiftyXMLParser** library and now I have to store 'senderName', 'messageBody', 'time', 'senderNumber' in **Realm** database.

Initially the tableView in ContactsViewController is empty. When user sends the message, It will first get stored in database and then I have to show the sender's Number/Name and messageBody in the tableViewCell. If same user sends the message just update the messageBody text. If different user sends the message, check if user exists in db, if not, add the user in the tableView and so on... check user for every message and likewise populate the tableView.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
class ContactsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

var messagesArray:[String] = [String]()
var messageBody : [String] = [String]()
var realm : Realm!
var userInfo = MessageData()

// viewDidLoad()    // assign tableView delegate, datasource and register the Nib.

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messagesArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = contactsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contactscell", for: indexPath) as! ContactsListCell
        cell.userNameLabel.text = messagesArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.userImageView.image = UIImage(named: "default-user")
        cell.messageBodyLabel.text = messageBody[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
} // end of class

extension ContactsViewController: XMPPStreamDelegate {

func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, didReceive message: XMPPMessage) {
    let string = message.prettyXMLString()
    let xml = try! XML.parse(string!)
    let messageSenderNo = xml["message"]["data”][“phoneNumber”].text
    let senderName = xml["message"]["data”][“name”].text
    let messageText = xml["message"]["data”][“text”].text
    let messageTime = xml["message"]["data"]["time"].text
    userInfo.messageFrom = messageSenderNo
    userInfo.messageBody = messageText
    userInfo.senderName = senderName

    realm = try! Realm()
            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(userInfo, update: true)     
            }

    let senderOfMsg:[String] = realm.objects(MessageData.self).value(forKey: "messageFrom") as! [String]!               
    let textMessage:[String] = realm.objects(MessageData.self).value(forKey: "messageBody") as! [String]!

    messagesArray = senderOfMsg                
    messageBody = textMessage
}   
}
```

This is my **Message** Class:

```
class MessageData: Object{

dynamic var messageFrom:String = ""
dynamic var messageBody:String = ""
dynamic var messageTime:String = ""
dynamic var messageSenderName:String = ""

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "messageFrom"
}

convenience init(messageFrom: String, messageBody: String, messageSenderFirstName: String, messageSenderLastName: String, message_id: String, messageTime: String){
    self.init()
    self.messageFrom = messageFrom
    self.messageBody = messageBody
    self.messageTime = messageTime
    self.messageSenderName = messageSenderName
}
}
```

I am using Realm for first time, so I don't know If I have done some fatal mistake. If at all the data gets saved in the realm database. For the first time tableView should be blank , but after there is data in the database, the tableView must show the contacts and messageBody. It should show previous messages if any, just like *WhatsApp* when user launches the app again. The data in the tableView should persist. Please tell me what I am doing wrong or have not done. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you need to call `UITableView`'s [`reloadData()` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata) (or one of the [methods to insert, remove, or delete rows](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview); see the "Inserting, Deleting, and Moving Rows and Sections" section), whenever you change the backing data. In this case that means when you set new values for `messagesArray` and `messagesBody` in your `xmppStream()` method, you need to call `reloadData()` or a similar method in order to tell the table view that its data source has been updated and that it needs to show new data.

More specifically: `messagesArray` and `messagesBody` aren't even necessary. Just use your Realm as a backing store. You can write your messages to a [`List`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html) inside your Realm, and then your `tableView(_:, cellForRowAt:)` method can directly call your model objects and load data out of them. You can then register a [collection notifier](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#collection-notifications) on that `List` so that whenever it changes, your application is automatically notified. Code inside your notifier can then reload the table view.

Comment: yes I added notification block in viewDidLoad() and updated UI in that block. Thanks :)